# Why would a facility use room numbers $3233$, $53$, $61$, $\infty$, $10^{100}$, $1729$, $4$, $1.61803$, $3.14159$, $1.33333$, $\sqrt{-1}$, $0$, $1$?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

I was part of TCS Ignite training after my BSc graduation from July 2007 to October 2007. The training space had a numbering system for its rooms such as 
$$3233,\; 53,\; 61, \;\infty, \; 10^{100}, \; 1729, \;4, \; 1.6180, \;3.1415, \;1.3333, \; \sqrt{-1}, \;0, \;1$$

What do these numbers mean in our life?

I had this question in mind during training. Before I ask this question to somebody, I happened to leave the organisation unexpectedly.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: It seems like most of them are either interesting mathematical constants, or other numbers that have a special name. For example, it's easy to recognize $3.14159$ as an approximation for $\pi$. Another example is $1729$, a so-called taxicab number (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)). A person interested in numbers (a numberphile) would look at $1729$ and smile, definitely, knowing its history and anecdotes related to it.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number , $10^{100}$ is called googol, $1729$ is a taxicab number and the non-integers are the golden ratio, $\pi$ , $\frac{4}{3}$ and $i$

Comment: @Peter May I know what is special about the value 4/3? If ∞ is not called as a number, then May I know what it is called?

Comment: @Ramesh I cannot see anything special about this number.

Comment: $\infty$ is used especially in limits. For example $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x+2}{x+1}=1$$ That means that if $x$ gets bigger and bigger the fraction tends to $1$

Comment: "infinity" is a concept. For example "There are infinite many prime numbers" means that we cannot list all the prime numbers because there is no last one.

Comment: @MattiP. Could you elaborate how these 13 numbers are interesting?

Answer (score 4):

To develop my comment, here are the main points about each of the numbers: (note that I'm not aware of how much you know about each of the numbers, so I don't know to what length I should tell about them. )

1. $3233$ is one of the least-popular numbers on the list. The most interesting fact about is that it can be written as a sum of two squares in two different ways: $23^2 + 52^2 = 32^2 + 47^2 = 3233$. Also, it's the hypotenuse of 2 Pythagorean triples: $3233^2 = 1185^2 + 3008^2 = 2175^2 + 2392^2$
2. $53$ is a prime number, and a Sophie Germain prime (since $2\times 53 + 1$ is also a prime). So also, not a very exciting number.
3. $61$ is again a prime number, but it's also the exponent of a Mersenne prime $2^{61}-1$.
4. $\infty$ is an immensely useful concept (NOT a number) in mathematics. It's a key tool in analysis and many other areas. Without it, we wouldn't have differential calculus and many other things.
5. $10^{100}$ is a quite large number, and it has been named 'googol'. It's not very much used in mathematics, but it has a funny name and Google is a derivative of this word, I believe as a result of a typo.
6. $1729$ is, in my opinion, the coolest number on the list. It can be associated with Srinivasa Ramanujan, a famous Indian mathematician. Read the Wikipedia page. $1729$ has been used in popular culture, in Futurama, for example.
7. $1.6180$ is an approximation for the Golden Ratio $\phi$. It's another popular number, that has been used to describe even the concept of beauty. It's used in art, photography, and it can be found in nature ...
8. $3.1415$ needs no introduction, it's an approximation for $\pi$. The ratio between the diameter and circumference of a circle, it's a real rock star in mathematics.
9. $1.333$ is an approximation for $\frac{4}{3}$. This is a tricky one and I find it difficult to say anything 'cool' about this number. Maybe the coolest thing about it can be that the volume of a sphere is equal to
   $$
    V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3
   $$
   where $r$ is the radius of the sphere. But maybe that's about it ...
10. $\sqrt{-1}$ is one form for the imaginary number $i$, which is another true rock star in mathematics, right up there with $\pi$. Students in school might be doubtful about this number at first, because it's not a 'real' number, but it's tremendously useful in mathematical analysis. Without it, many technologies would not exist, because for example signal processing uses $i$. MP3 music files wouldn't exist without $i$ ...
11. $0$ and $1$ are the some of the real building blocks of mathematics. They are used so much that it's even hard to start describing how useful they are. But I will say this: The previously mentioned $\pi$ and $i$, together with $0$ and $1$, are used in the very beautiful result
    $$
    e^{i\pi }+ 1 = 0
    $$

Strangely enough, $e\approx 2.71828$ was not mentioned, it's also a famous number.

Comment: I left $4$ out of the list because I can't really think of anything to say about it.

Comment: $4 = 2+2 = 2\cdot 2 = 2^2=\,^22=2\uparrow^n2$ for all $n$ in [Knuth's Up-Arrow Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/53_(number)), 53 is also the smallest prime that does not divide the order of any sporadic group.

Comment: $3233$, $53$ and $61$ are closely related: $3233 = 53\cdot 61$.

Comment: @MattiP. I had no clue about 0 and 1. But I got some idea based on your response now.

Answer (score 1):

1. 3233 is semiprime and a product of other two prime numbers in the list 53 & 61. 3233 is the biggest room in the facility and can accommodate 200 people. Rooms 53 & 61 can accommodate 100 people each. All other rooms are labs accommodating 24 people with computers. In **RSA algorithm** these three numbers 3233, 53, 61 can be used.
2. I think 4 signifies four color theorem of Graph Theory.
3. As per the below book link 1.333 is called as pythagorean number derived from a pythagorean triple (4, 3, 5).

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_w9MDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22pythagorean+number%22+(1.333)&source=bl&ots=qO0wQGLdXc&sig=ACfU3U2RF0tFmhVdY9Cut7IYztQ3eKqVBw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-k5bzzODgAhUYCTQIHVKfD88Q6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22pythagorean%20number%22%20(1.333)&f=false

The above facility was designed by people who worked in various universities and organizations such as NSA of United States and returned to India after 20 years.

This facility Head name is Srinivasan Raman which resembles the Mathematician name Srinivasa Ramanujan. Often, I used to think this space was not created accidentally. It has a purpose behind that. This training space is full of knowledge.

But I was not lucky enough to continue working in this space. Sometimes I used to think about these numbers and figure out what they mean. I had idea about few numbers. But, I am not sure about the number 1.333 still.